# How do I convert my HTML5 game made with phaser into a exe file with electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, game-development, phaser-framework

**Good Morning Devs**
I just want to know how to convert my html5 game into an **EXE** file with Electron

Directory : [Directory Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iFsa.png)

I installed Phaser and Electron with npm.

I am using the phaser.min.js file and downloaded the Phaser with npm to get better Intellisence.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning Phaser</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<script src="src/phaser.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/scenes/Scene1.js"></script>
<script src="src/scenes/Scene2.js"></script>
<script src="src/game.js"></script>

<body>
    
</body>
```

Scene1.js

```
class Scene1 extends Phaser.Scene {
constructor () {
    super("bootgame");
}

preload () {
    this.load.image("background", "assets/images/background.png")
}

create () {
    this.add.text(20, 20,"Loading Game .....")
    this.scene.start("playgame");
}

update () {

}
}
```

Scene2.js

```
class Scene2 extends Phaser.Scene {
constructor () {
    super("playgame");
}

preload () {
    this.load.image("background", "assets/images/background.png")
    this.load.image("ship", "assets/images/ship.png")
    this.load.image("ship2", "assets/images/ship2.png")
    this.load.image("ship3", "assets/images/ship3.png")
}

create () {
    this.background = this.add.image(0, 0, "background")
    this.background.setOrigin(0, 0)

    this.ship = this.add.image(config.width/2 - 50, config.height/2, "ship")
    this.ship2 = this.add.image(config.width/2, config.height/2, "ship2")
    this.ship3 = this.add.image(config.width/2 + 50, config.height/2, "ship3")

    this.add.text(20, 20, "Playing Game", {font: "25px Arial", fill: "yellow"});
}

update () {
    
}
}
```

game.js

```
var config = {
width : 256,
height : 272,
backgroundColor : 0x000000,
scene : [
    Scene1, Scene2 
],
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

index.js (For the Electron package I installed)

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

function createWindow() {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 256,
    height: 272,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    }
})
win.setMenuBarVisibility(false);
win.loadFile('index.html');
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
```

This is making me only to Preview the App, not to Build and Export.

I am following a tutorial to learn Phaser Game Development with HTML5.

I am just curious to know how to convert my HTML5 game to an EXE file and distribute it.

**Thank, You**

Comment: I personally use `electron-builder` as it supports auto-updates, I have never used `electron-forge` but it'll work too. `electron-packager` I wouldn't recommend, it doesn't make a standalone .exe. Here's a guide on how to [get started with `electron-builder`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder#quick-setup-guide)